# Имя сайта в рунете на английском

Tags: информатика, психолингвистика

Планируется создание сайта в рунете, целевая аудитория - спортивные болельщики

- имя сайта: словосочетание из двух английских слов
- домен: .zone

Будут ли эти моменты иметь негативное влияние?

Будут интересны любые соображения на этот счет, в том числе, Ваше субьективное мнение

Comment: По-моему, этот вопрос абсолютно вне сферы russian.se plus it's completely subjective, there's no correct answer here. I'm voting to close it.

Comment: Вы имеете доменную зону _.zone_ буквально? (Да, такая оказывается [существует](https://www.nic.ru/cgi/na.cgi?js_on=on&step=n_a.ntld&zone=zone).) Из каких, позвольте узнать соображений, она была выбрана?

Comment: @Dmitry Alexandrov - в домене com все нормальные имена заняты, сайтов зачастую нет, но имя зарегистрировано; домен ru не устраивает, как и любой другой национальный - в планы входит создание версий сайта на других языках в одном домене, русская будет первой; из остальных доменов .zone по смыслу неплохо подходит, но окончательный выбор еще не сделан

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming a website.

Comment: (любое бросское английское слово или хорошо узнаваемое русское с устойчиво закрепившейся транслитерацией)fan.zone - russianfan.zone например (но zone и вправду не самый удачный выбор для домена)

Answer (score 1):

Site names in Latin script, particularly in English are a de facto standard in Runet because for a long time there was no technical possibility of domain names in Cyrillic (and still there can be trobles with it in some browsers). And I strongly discourage the transliteration of Russian words for the purpose. So I think either English name or a name originating from Latin, Greek or a similar sounding invented name written in Latin script would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Про английский язык в имени уже сказала Anixx, мне кроме как +1 к ее словам добавить нечего.

Что до доменной зоны [.zone](https://www.nic.ru/cgi/na.cgi?js_on=on&step=n_a.ntld&zone=zone), то вы, здесь, вероятно, полагаете возможной ассоциацию с «зоной» — местом заключения. Мне сложно оценить психологию болельщика, но если намека на неприятную ассоциацию можно легко избежать, то лучше так и сделать, не правда ли?

Но у меня есть и более кардинальное мнение на этот счет (возможно, из-за него вы сочтете меня ретроградом :-). Я полагаю, что все эти [NewGTLD](https://www.nic.ru/dns/domain/new_gtld/list.html): .club, .vodka, .sexy и прочие вовсе не стоят того, чтоб их использовать. Имя веб-сайта должно быть узнаваемым именно как имя веб-сайта *само по себе*.

Вы пишете на постере «football.ru. Болей за любимую команду онлайн!» — и все понятно, ибо все знают, что такое «точка-ру» или «точка-ком». Никто пока не знает что такое «точка-zone». И я не случайно написал *ком* кириллицей, а *zone* — латиницей, подумайте, как это *zone* должно *звучать*, когда его будут диктовать по телефону или рекламировать по радио, например.

Comment: Дмитрий, вы в точности изложили мои мысли :) Идеальный вариант - это выкупить .com, однако у проекта нет инвестора. Когда-нибудь может быть...

Comment: @u.hrybok Я правильно понял, что задавая вопрос, вы искали человека, который изложит вам ваши мысли? Интересный подход, надо взять на вооружение. :-)

Comment: Нет, просто у меня было только мое личное мнение. Мне интересно мнение других людей. А может быть существует даже научный подход к даннома вопросу.

Comment: @u.hrybok Что до выкупа `.com`, то, быть может, выкуп `.org`, `.net`, `.info` будет по карману. Я не могу, к сожалению, проверить, какие из них доступны на каких условиях, ибо вы не опубликовали желаемое имя (и правильно сделали, сквоттеры не дремлют). Но есть еще кучка национальных зон, что перестали восприниматься как таковые: `.tv`, `.dj` и т. д. Все что угодно будет лучше, чем `.zone`.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Если учесть что продажа доменных зон .tv составляет большую часть прибыли государства Тувалу, эта конкретная зона скорее всего дороже чем .com.